# Scroll bar not showing the full content in right side in HTML doc

Tags: html, css

I plan to create a horizontal scroll bar. One div element wraps all contents.The problem is when user scrolls, it is not fully scrolled until end of the right. So I am not able to see the content at end. I need a help to fix it.

CSS

```
.fr {
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow-x: auto;
    background: pink;
    padding: 20px;
}

.c1 {
    position: relative;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 18px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 9px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    padding: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="fr">
    <div class="c1">
        <h3>...</h3>
        <h4>....</h4>
        <h5>.....</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="c1">
        <h3>...</h3>
        <h4>....</h4>
        <h5>.....</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="c1">
        <h3>...</h3>
        <h4>....</h4>
        <h5>.....</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your `overflow-x: auto` on `.fr`. This restricts how far across the scrollbar can go. Removing this solves the `width` problem, but will still have the background only go to the edge of the container. You likely want to move this to the parent element, in this case `body`.

```css
body {
  background: pink;
}

.fr {
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 20px;
}

.c1 {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 18px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 9px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  padding: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fr">
  <div class="c1">
    <h3>...</h3>
    <h4>....</h4>
    <h5>.....</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="c1">
    <h3>...</h3>
    <h4>....</h4>
    <h5>.....</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="c1">
    <h3>...</h3>
    <h4>....</h4>
    <h5>.....</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to remove scrollbar. Or can you explain more clearly what is your problem.

```
.fr{
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
```